# Using change of variable technique to show uniform distribution

Tags: probability, probability-theory

Problem:Let X have a logistic distribution with PDF $f_X(x)=\frac{e^{-x}}{(1+e^{-x})^2}$, $-\infty<x<\infty$. Show $Y=\frac{1}{1+e^{-X}}$ has an uniform distribution over (0,1).

Answer:$f_Y(y)=\frac{1}{|u'(x)|} f_X(x)=\frac{(1+e^{-x})^2}{e^{-x}} \frac{e^{-x}}{(1+e^{-x})^2}$=1 which is a constant. Hence it is an uniform distribution.

I am wondering there is another approach, which is the CDF technique. Does it work here too?

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: @NCh Is it right?

Comment: Yes, it is right. And the question is unclear nevertheless: you have to show it is uniform distribution and you get it is. What are your doubts?

Comment: @NCh see my edit